# How to get roles for the current authenticated user in Oracle ORDS?

Tags: oracle-ords

How to get roles for the current authenticated user in Oracle ORDS?
I'm using basic authentication, ORDS is deployed on Tomcat server.
I would like to have a special role so only certain users can run REST Enabled SQL.